# Beagleboard Black all GPIOs are activated by a single GPIO

Tags: gpio, beagleboard

Earlier I was having a problem with BeagleBoard Black Rev C , which I discussed in the question below.

[GPIO.HIGH,LOW doesn't up LED Beagleboard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200264/gpio-high-low-doesnt-up-led-beagleboard?noredirect=1#comment419076_200264)

I've found the real problem. Whenever I turn any single GPIO pin (say , P8_3) , all the other GPIO pins under P8 also becomes HIGH at the same time, that's why I was having problem lighting up an LED by taking both +ve and -ve from two GPIOs from P8. Same goes for P9. In stead if I take one GPIO from P9 and make it HIGH and another from P8 and make it LOW , the LED is lighting up properly(also I checked using Multimeter and its showing potential differences properly). But the problem arises as all the other GPIOs of P9 are HIGH and all of P8 are LOW.

I want to change individual GPIOs HIGH or LOW whenever I wish. What can be the possible problem? Do I need to update the image? But I don't think that would be the reason of this problem.

EDIT: Posting the python code.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setup("P8_3", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup("P8_5", GPIO.OUT)

while True:
   GPIO.output("P8_3", GPIO.HIGH)
   GPIO.output("P8_5", GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: Please post code

Comment: Did it. Its a simple python code to keep the LED on.

Comment: P8 Pin 3 and Pin 5 are part of the MMC (Sd card) gpio. Are you sure those are free? (Not sure which BBB your using, I'm looking at Rev C). Try P8_7 and P8_9 instead.

Comment: I'm using RevC. and yes I've tried them too. Same problem.